# What is simple coincidence?

Tags: probability

I was reading OkTrends and [came across this](http://blog.okcupid.com/index.php/page/3/):

> In fact, 32% of successful couples
>   agreed on all of them—which is 3.7×
>   the rate of simple coincidence.

So, my question is: what is simple coincidence? How is it calculated?

I can't find a Wikipedia article about *simple* coincidence, and nowhere can I find a numerical definition. So, I'm confused about how the author got "3.7x" the rate of "simple" coincidence.

Comment: According to the legend for that graphic, "simple coincidence" is synonymous with "expected from pure chance."  The latter might mean that if we assume the answers to all three questions are independent and if a random man's answers are matched to a random woman's answers, then they should match 32%/3.7 of the time.

Comment: @whuber: What would you bet that figure hasn't been corrected for the (rather large) number of multiple comparisons present?

Comment: @Cardinal Criticizing the statistical methods on that site would be like shooting turtles in a barrel: too easy, messy, time-consuming, and with little value.  Let them have their fun...

Comment: @whuber: I suppose that's true. Only thing is, it appears they (actually) believe they're doing something real. Also, how many times have you shot turtles in a barrel? :)

Answer (score 1):

Answered by @whuber.

> According to the legend for that graphic, "simple coincidence" is
>   synonymous with "expected from pure chance." The latter might mean
>   that if we assume the answers to all three questions are independent
>   and if a random man's answers are matched to a random woman's answers,
>   then they should match 32%/3.7 of the time.